# getting a string and array of strings value from api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have an api call which is returning me sometimes a string and sometimes array of strings, the difference is when i get `Arrayofstrings`

i get it like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

how can i display

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

in my vue div code

```
<div>
{{ item.value }}
</div>
```

any idea

the value is item.value which is already running a loop inside a main div so i wonder how will this be displayed

```
<div class="alues" v-for="(item,index) in charges" :key="index">
<div> -- this is where i need the array of strings to show up
    {{ item.value }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whether the value which you get in `item.value` will be sometimes string or array of strings?

Comment: yes array of strings and sometimes just a singe number

Comment: You need to add condition check to display the data, Can you check this example? https://codesandbox.io/s/v-for-in-v-for-v-model-forked-81v6o7

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement by using [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    charges: ['1', '2', '4', '5', ['2', '6', '7', '8'], '11', '12']
  },
  mounted() {
    this.charges = this.charges.flatMap(num => num);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item,index) in charges" :key="index">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</div>
```